# Add Fragment to a View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to customize a Popup Window on a click of the button on the top right. (Image is posted at the bottom)

```
    ImageButton menuButton = view.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
    menuButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        View popup = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, null);
        popup.findViewById(R.id.clear_button).setOnClickListener(button -> {
            food_pool.AddAll(Menu).Shuffle();
            Menu.Clear();
        });
        FoodListFragment fragment = new FoodListFragment();
        fragment.SetData(food_pool);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.food_list_frame, fragment).commit();
        // Create popup window.
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popup, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // Set popup window animation style.
        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.push_up_in);
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.update();
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(menuButton, 1, 1);
    });
```

I am able to instantiate the view. But how do I properly find the Fragment in the `fragment_menu`?

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.food_list_frame, fragment).commit();` fails because it cannot find the `food_list_frame`. I have also tried `getChildFragmentManager()`, which doesn't work as well.

This is the xml of `fragment_menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/food_list_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/menu_toolbar" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my [project](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/) and the java code is in the [RandomFragment](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/RandomFragment.java).

[image]

Comment: try placeholderview to get this kind of view with accept and reject and reload

Comment: @VasudevVyas Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tinder-swipe-view-example-3eca9b0d4794 try this example .. may be it may help you

Comment: The problem is that your activity does not contain any view with id `food_list_frame`. You are inflating a layout but that layout is never attached to the activity so the fragment manager can't find it. You probably should look at `DialogFragment` for this functionality.

Comment: @Froyo Yes I know this issue so I am wondering how I should do this.

Comment: 1. Use `DialogFragment` 2. Don't use dialogs. 3. Use a custom view in your dialog.

Comment: @VasudevVyas Thank you that's super helpful!!!

Comment: @Froyo Could you please take a look at my [fragment](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/RandomFragment.java)? I want to display a `MenuDialog` and it is not there, and the code of that is in the `menuButton.setOnClickListener`. Do I just normally call `dialog.showNow`? But I don't to display it like that. I want it to be like a card dangling there.